# DataGrip connect mysql

Tags: mysql, datagrip, econnrefused

this my error:

```
DBMS: MySQL (no ver.)
Case sensitivity: plain=mixed, delimited=exact
Connection refused: connect.
```

please help me solve,
My English is not good
thanks

I tried to find the answer on the Internet, but it didn't work

this `idea.log`:

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2023-08-15 18:14:29,862 [ 139990]   INFO - #c.i.d.d.DatabaseConnectionEstablisher - Connecting to: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
2023-08-15 18:14:29,862 [ 139990]   INFO - #c.i.d.d.DatabaseConnectionEstablisher - Auth provider: user-pass
2023-08-15 18:14:29,863 [ 139991]   INFO - #c.i.d.d.DatabaseCredentialsAuthProvider - Connecting as: root
2023-08-15 18:14:29,869 [ 139997]   WARN - #c.i.d.d.DatabaseConnectionEstablisher - Connecting to: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
2023-08-15 18:14:29,869 [ 139997]   WARN - #c.i.d.d.DatabaseConnectionEstablisher - [08S01] Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2023-08-15 18:14:38,382 [ 148510]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2023-08-15 18:14:39,885 [ 150013]   INFO - #c.i.d.d.s.DbSrcModificationSession$CountedThreadExecutor - DbSrcWriter stopped
```

Comment: "Connection refused" usually means there's no MySQL server running  on the machine you specified at the port you specified. And, you know, JetBrains has a competent support staff.

Comment: Is it possible to share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after reproducing the issue?

Comment: I have not installed MySQL, I want to use DataGrip directly to manage the database, and I am not familiar with using DataRrip

Comment: If you didn't install MySQL then what DB should be used? There should be DB at address "localhost:3306" to work with.

Comment: "I want to modify the database but I don't want the database to exist" .. oh .. okay .. well so you want your cake but not to eat it ?

Comment: DataGrip is a client app, to connect to a database server. You have only half of the client-server arrangement. You must install a database server. Without that, a database client is useless.

Answer (score 1):

DataGrip doesn't install any DB engine; it only connects to via JDBC.

For the case when you've got only SQL scripts, you can refer to [DDL data source functionality](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/ddl-data-sources.html).